# Why does a jailbroken iPhone always ask to restart Springboard after installing a new app?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia

I just jailbroke my iPhone and it went well.

Why does a jailbroken iPhone always ask to restart springboard everytime an app is installed from Cydia? It's so annoying. It's like installing an app on a Mac and having to reboot the machine. I jailbroke using redsnow.

Any answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't always - only when the new app directly affects the interface. So when you install command-line only functionality there is no need to respring - at the other end of the scale you would also need to respring every time you change a theme in, say, winterboard, even though you are not installing a new app.

The reason for this behaviour at both ends of this spectrum is that none of the jailbreak 'tweaks' can affect the springboard while it's running - they have to change the filed copy and then restart with a new version of springboard...

Answer (score 1):

Often jailbreak apps hook into springboard to be able to control views that get displayed or user interactions. A good and popular example of this is MyWi. It uses the build in tethering bar to display when the device is currently tethering. To do this is needs to restart springboard so it can hook into it properly.

Answer (score 0):

When the application needs to be "installed" as a "icon" app, it will install as a **system** app even when CyDelete is installed. System apps differ from normal apps as system apps CANNOT be deleted easily while normal apps can be deleted from the Settings app but system apps, when installed, because they cannot be deleted from Springboard, it requires a respring to "update" Springboard.